# With $f$ defined on the unit disc $D: x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$, and given that $\nabla f(1,0) = (1, 1)$, could $f$ reach its maximal value on $D$ at $(1, 0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

> $f$ is a continuous function with continuous partial derivatives.
>
> With $f$ defined on the unit disc $D: x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$, and given that
> $\nabla f(1,0) = (1, 1)$, could $f$ reach its maximal value on $D$ at $(1, 0)$?

I know that the answer is no, but I am trying to prove how. I would love to share my input, but I'm at a complete loss as to what to do here. Any hint or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on Robert's hint: the directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $v$ is $\nabla f(1,0)\cdot v=(1,1)\cdot v$. If the directional derivative is positive, the function is increasing in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: There are directions you can go from $(1,0)$ that stay inside $D$ and have positive dot product with $(1,1)$.

Comment: I think I understand, what if the given point was $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$? Then we wouldn't have a direction to go, would we?